# Apache Airflow on Docker is not starting all services

Tags: docker, airflow

I am trying to run the official apache airflow docker image on my Mac

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html
But after starting all services using docker compose up, I get:

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS                      PORTS                              NAMES
01a02c48714d   apache/airflow:2.0.2     "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   39 seconds ago       Up 30 seconds               8080/tcp                           airflow_test_airflow-worker_1
ae7896c8dff7   apache/airflow:2.0.2     "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   39 seconds ago       Up 27 seconds (unhealthy)   0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp             airflow_test_airflow-webserver_1
871e38f34520   apache/airflow:2.0.2     "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   39 seconds ago       Up 30 seconds               8080/tcp                           airflow_test_airflow-scheduler_1
b7381eb021a6   apache/airflow:2.0.2     "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   39 seconds ago       Up 28 seconds (unhealthy)   0.0.0.0:5555->5555/tcp, 8080/tcp   airflow_test_flower_1
```

How to resolve the 'unhealthy' services. The web server is not returning any requests at localhost:8080

Comment: Were you able to make it work? Did you figure out the issue?